# How to get the return value of the block passed to eval method?

Tags: ruby, eval, return-value, yield

I want to implement something like a sandbox which can

- eval given string
- execute given block in the same context with eval
- return the result of block

The aim of the sandbox is to inspect the contents - functions, variables, e.t.c. - of vulnerable codes.

Here is my spec

```
it 'returns return value of given block' do
  value = Sandbox.secure_eval('hoge = ["hoge", "fuga"]') do
    hoge[0]
  end
  expect(value).to eq('hoge')
end
```

and, this is my implementation of sandbox

```
require 'timeout'
module Sandbox
  def self.secure_eval(code, timeout: 5, safe_level: 2)
    raise ArgumentError, 'please set call back by block' unless block_given?

    proc = Proc.new do
      Timeout::timeout timeout do
        $SAFE = safe_level
        eval code do
          yield
        end
      end
    end

    proc.call
  end
end
```

But #secure_eval returns the result of eval, in this case ["hoge", "fuga"], and cannot capture the return value of the block.

How can I make it?

Comment: I don't think the block is called anywhere - `eval` does not accept a block...

Comment: To quote [Ruby Security](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/security_rdoc.html): "However, `$SAFE` does not provide a secure environment for executing untrusted code." You should **never** rely on `$SAFE` or any other generic "safe code execution" mechanism built-in to Ruby (or into most other languages) to protect you from harm when executing untrusted (and potentially malicious) code. Your sandbox is not a sandbox at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return the result of eval to the block using `yield`. You just had to `yield` the value; thus I changed your `yield` to `yield eval code`. In the block you give to `Sandbox.secure_eval` you have to then bind this result to a block variable. The result of `secure_eval` will be the result of the block, like you wanted.

```
proc = Proc.new do
  Timeout::timeout timeout do
    $SAFE = safe_level
    yield eval code # <= This line changed
  end
end

Sandbox.secure_eval('hoge = ["hoge", "fuga"]') { |hoge| hoge[0] }
# => "hoge"

Sandbox.secure_eval('2 ** 4') { |result| result - 5 }
# => 11
```

---

In response to your comment; it turns out that with the aid of [Kernel#Binding](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Binding.html), we can get it to work more or less like you wanted. It feels rather like a hack so use it with caution.

I use the Binding to evaluate the code, which will have access to all defined variables. In addition, I define a `method_missing` for the Binding class so we can access the variables more easily. Without it, you would need to do `eval('varname')` rather than just `varname`. Per the comment of @hakcho who mentioned the monkey-patch solution that was in place is not ideal, I now use refinements which only locally changes the behavior of Binding (i.e., the method_missing implementation).

I have added an explicit `block` parameter to your method, which I use with `instance_eval` instead of `yield`. We can then access the variables directly in the block.

```
require 'timeout'

module Sandbox
  refine Binding do
    def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
      self.eval(meth.to_s)
    end
  end

  def self.secure_eval(code, timeout: 5, safe_level: 2, &block)
    raise ArgumentError, 'please set call back by block' unless block_given?

    proc = Proc.new do
      Timeout::timeout timeout do
        $SAFE = safe_level
        binding = binding()
        binding.eval(code)
        binding.instance_eval(&block)
      end
    end

    proc.call
  end
end

using Sandbox # Activate the refinement so we can use x, y, z directly
Sandbox.secure_eval('x = [1,2,3]; y = 0; z = { key: "Hello!" }') do
   x[1]    # => 2
   y       # => 0
   z[:key] # => "Hello!"
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Your code seems to work, but I want my sandbox works as bellow:

    Sandbox.secure_eval('hoge = ["hoge", "fuga"];piyo = "piyo"') { hoge[0] }
    # => "hoge"

Are there any way?

Comment: @Mekajiki Ah so you want to be able to access any variables that you declared inside `eval`.. I don't know if that is possible, `eval` just returns the value of the last expression but not of intermediate expressions. Perhaps it is possible but I do not immediately know a way.

Comment: @Mekajiki I have updated my post with a way to access other defined variables.

Comment: You have to add `*args` and `block` to `eval` in `Binding` but doing that about the block is not trivial at all.

Comment: @hakcho I was thinking that too, but it works fine without it. Remember it is used to "call" variables, not methods with parameters and/or a block. So the args and block will always be empty unless I am missing something.

Comment: Thanks, this was a quality Ruby answer.  Can you share an interesting link that demos the use of Binding?

Comment: @NewAlexandria Unfortunately, I cannot. I ran into Binding from the Kernel#eval docs page and this was the first time I used it myself :) But thank you for the nice words.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers sorry for copy-pasting your answear but please remove the monkey patching of `Binding`. It could bring alot of problems later.

Comment: @hakcho I added the usage of refinements, which now require `using Sandbox` to enable the patched Binding behavior rather than enabling it globally.